# Associate multiple tables with a single table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, primary-key

I have a RDBMS database and I need to associate a column in a new table to multiple other existing tables whose schema can't be changed.

The new table looks something like this,

```
UUID(pk)   PartId(pk) Somecolumn1 SomeColumn2
asdf56das  0001       val1        val2
u44ighhuh  0002       val3        val4
u44ighhuh  0003       val5        val6
```

I want to associate UUID column with data from other tables.

One method is to add a XML column to this new table which would store the associations as,

```
<tablename><pkcolumn1>value</pkcolumn1> 
<pkcolumn2>value2</pkcolumn2>...........<pkcolumnN>valueN</pkcolumnN> 
</tablename>
```

With this approach there is some performance cost involved in creating and parsing XML. Is there a better way to associate these tables?

Comment: The more conventional approach is to have intermediate "many-to-many" tables that list the IDs from both and whatever other info you need about the relationship, but the details may depend of a few other factors you haven't mentioned: How many other tables could there be "relationships" with? Are the identifiers in the other tables always of the same data type?

Comment: The problem with having intermediate table is that we would need to create a new intermediate table for every addition of the "other table". The number of other tables is 4 as of now, but the number can increase as we scale. Also the data types and number of identifiers in other tables can vary.

Comment: If the relationships are being used in different ways, then 4 intermediate tables doesn't seem like a big deal to me, but your level of effort may depend on your schema and your application. Either way, each new "relationship" type will need either a new intermediate table that you can query with simple joins, or it'll need a new application routine that builds the query based on the parsed XML. I'm a DBA, so clearly the former is more attractive to me.

Comment: Thanks @Brad I agree with you that would be a more cleaner way to solve this.